# Mongo DB connection using spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, rest

> com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:
> internal_error

While trying to connect mongodb using Springboot getting error

> MongoSocketWriteExcepption caused by javax.net.ssl.sslexception

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to atlas cluster on cloud, you can take a look at your ip address again, if your current ip address is added to the access list under Network Access option. So, on Atlas home page, in left bar, you will see Security --> network access --> ip access list --> Add current ip address.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the provided .pem file to your JRE cacerts which is a certificate provided by MongoDB server.

The certificate need to be imported to  ${java_home}/jre/lib/security/cacerts

using the command `keytool -import -trustcacerts -file testCA.pem -keystore cacerts -storepass "changeit"`

Also, make sure you are using right JRE while executing your code where the .pem certificate was exported.

```
  //Following properties sets required ssl settings while executing the code.

  System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",JAVA_HOME + "\\lib\\security\\cacerts");
  System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","changeit");

//Create SSL context
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
    .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
    .build();

//Apply SSL settings
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
    .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
    .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder()
            .sslContext(sslContext)
            .build()).build();

//Create MongoClient using ssl settings
MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings);
```